# How to add second level to Magento admin config acl?

Tags: magento

I need this for custom module I'm working on. So, for example, I have main module which creates tab in config menu:

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule_all">
                                        <title>My Module</title>
                                    </mymodule>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Then i have mu sub-module which belongs to this tab:

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mymodule>
                                        <children>
                                            <submodule translate="title" module="submodule">
                                                <title>Sub Module</title>
                                            </submodule>
                                        </children>
                                    </mymodule>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

So with above example config - sub-module just not visible in role resources configuration.

Removing  from sub-module acl kinda helps, it became visible, but it's on the same level as mymodule now, and this is not what i want.

Does Magento allow only one level acl in config section? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have as many levels as many you want in acl. There is nothing seems to be wrong in your code.
So to error may be coming from somewhere else in you config.xml, just make sure that every tags are properly closed.
Then follow these steps

1.Try removing title and module attributes in your tags.
bcz these build dependency over Helper class.

2.Then edit you first config.xml in this way

```
<mymodule>
    <title>My Module</title>
    <children>    
        <submodule>
            <title>Sub Module</title>
        </submodule>
    <children>
</mymodule>
```

If you can see proper acl resource tree then it means there nothing wrong with My Module.so Concentrate on your Sub Module for any mistake.